# Capture icv2.imshow and save it as an image

Tags: python

I'm trying to save the output imgCanny as an image/screenshot. How do I incorporate this so a screenshot of that window can be captured when a certain key is pressed. I am taking the live feed from the webcam and processing it. I would then like to be able to press a key on the keyboard to capture and save a screenshot of the imgCanny Window.

```
cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)



cv2.waitKey(0)

cap.set(3, frameWidth)   
cap.set(4, frameHeight)
def empty(a):
pass
cv2.namedWindow("Parameters")
cv2.resizeWindow("Parameters", 640, 240)
cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold1", "Parameters", 150, 500, empty)
cv2.createTrackbar("Threshold2", "Parameters", 255, 500, empty)
def getContours(img, imgContour):
contours, hierarchy = cv2.findContours(img, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, 
cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE) #retreival method. External, only extreme 
outer contours
#change APPROX to simple for less points

    #remove small bits of noise
   for cnt in contours:
    area = cv2.contourArea(cnt)
    # Used to flatted the array containing
    # the co-ordinates of the vertices.
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(cnt, 0.009 * cv2.arcLength(cnt, True), 
    True)
    n = approx.ravel()
    i = 0

    for j in n:
        if (i % 2 == 0):


            x = n[i]
            y = n[i + 1]


            # String containing the co-ordinates.

            string = str(int(x / 3.5)) + " " + str(int(y / 3.5))
            print(string)



            if (i == 0):
                # text on topmost co-ordinate.
                cv2.putText(imgContour, "", (x, y),
                            font, 0.5, (255, 0, 0))
            else:
                # text on remaining co-ordinates.
                cv2.putText(imgContour, string, (x, y),
                            font, 0.5, (0, 255, 0))
        i = i + 1
    if area > 3000:
      cv2.drawContours(imgContour, cnt, -1, (255, 0, 255), 1)
      peri = cv2.arcLength(cnt, True) #true means contour is closed






while True:
success, img = cap.read()
imgContour = img.copy()
imgBlur = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (31, 31), 1)
imgGray = cv2.cvtColor(imgBlur, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
threshold1 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold1", "Parameters")
threshold2 = cv2.getTrackbarPos("Threshold2", "Parameters")
imgCanny = cv2.Canny(imgGray, threshold1, threshold2)
kernel = np.ones((5, 5))
imgDil = cv2.dilate(imgCanny, kernel, iterations=1)
getContours(imgDil, imgContour)
#cv2.imshow("Results", img )
#cv2.imshow("Mask", imgGray)
cv2.imshow("Canny", imgCanny)
cv2.imshow("Dilated", imgContour)
cv2.imshow("Test", imgDil)
key = cv2.waitKey(100)

if key == 27: #kills with Esc
    break
cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Comment: What do you mean when a certain key is pressed? `imgCanny` is already an image, you can just save it using `cv2.imwrite()`.

Comment: Pressing for example "c" on the keyboard. How would I implement cv2.imwrite() into my code?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I've added the full code now.